# NoMethodError in PinsController#index, undefined method `to_a' for #<Class:0x0000010150ec98>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting this error in my pins_controller from the one month course and have no idea how to solve it. Here's my controller.

---

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]

def index
  @pins = Pin.to_a
end

def show
end

def new
 @pin = current_user.pins.build
end

def edit
end

def create
  @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)
if @pin.save
  redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.'
else
  render action: 'new'
end
```

end

def update
    if @pin.update(pin_params)
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

def destroy
    @pin.destroy
    redirect_to pins_url
  end

private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_pin
      @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    end

```
def correct_user
  @pin = current_user.pins.find_by(id: params[:id])
  redirect_to pins_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this pin" if @pin.nil?
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def pin_params
  params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :image)
end
```

end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have

```
Pin.all
```

instead of

```
Pin.to_a
```

in your controller.

Comment: I agree with the `.all`, but do we even need `.to_a` here? I'd rather have the Pins as a collection than an array (even though they're very similar)

Comment: @Mallanaga, thanks for suggestion, you're right. What's more, in Rails versions before 4.0.0 `all` actually returns an array, so calling on it `to_a` is pointless.

Comment: @MarekLipka I think it should return an ActiveRecord::Relation object, this also allows for rails to lazy load the result only if it encounters the instance var in the views.

Comment: @JosephSilvashy it does in Rails 4 and author uses Rails 4 (strong params).